# Manipulating text file using batch jobs

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Good day

I need to put the currency after the account number that is on field `:25:`
currency is on field `:62F:`
account number is no field `:25:`
how would I take a text file that looks like this:

`{1:}{2:1000U}{4:
:20:100798
:25:100798
:28C:1519/1
:60F:C151116TZS0,00
:62F:C151117TZS0,00
-}{5:{CHK:691494CC8019}}
{1:}{2:1007N}{3:{108:CBC484}}{4:
:20:MTID00222
:25:31691035174 
:28C:00222/00002
:60M:C151117CAD0,00
:61:1511D1000,003D3
SND FIRNZAJJ

:61:15117D1182,70S1

:62F:C151117CAD184,36
:64:C151117CAD184,36
-}{5:{CHK:76D55C3FE9DA}}`

to look like this:
NOTE the currency in field in `:62F:` is not always the same.

`{1:}{2:1000U}{4:
:20:100798
:25:100798USD
:28C:1519/1
:60F:C151116USD0,00
:62F:C151117USD0,00
-}{5:{CHK:691494CC8019}}
{1:}{2:1007N}{3:{108:CBC484}}{4:
:20:MTID00222
:25:31691035174 
:28C:00222/00002
:60M:C151117CAD0,00
:61:1511D1000,003D3

:61:15117D1182,70S1

:62F:C151117CAD184,36
:64:C151117CAD184,36
-}{5:{CHK:76D55C3FE9DA}}`

thanks

existing code:

```
echo off 
SET TempFile=Temp.txt 
findstr ":25:1234" test.txt >> result1.txt 
findstr /n ":25:1234" test.txt >> result2.txt 
findstr /i ":62M: \.:62F:" test.txt >> currency.txt 
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%G IN (result2.txt) DO echo %%G >>result3.txt 
pause
```

here is more relavante data : `{1:F01FIRNZAJJACLS0991710374}{2:O9500614151118CLSBUS33AXXX12605310901511181314N}{3:{108:S201511182092336}}{4:
:20:S201511182092336
:25:100798
:28C:46/1
:60F:C151118JPY0,
:61:1511181118D805000000,NFEXO201511180000023//V2015111800B3B00
:61:1511181118D1373000000,NFEXFXTMAV68177721A//V201511180084C07
:61:1511181118C2178000000,NFEXFXTMAV68135827B//V201511180053B5F
:62F:C151118JPY0,
-}{5:{CHK:D18476DD1D81}}
{1:F01FIRNZAJJAXXX0991711421}{2:O9502036151118MHCBJPJTBXXX47427596761511181336N}{4:
:20:ST 1118/0685010
:25:0685010
:28C:00216/001
:60F:C151118JPY4945624,
:61:1511181118CY26635000,NTRFNONREF//TRF062/363192
B/O FIRSTRAND BANK LTD
:61:1511181118DY2500,NTRFS657DRTSF1807511//TCT023/694154
:61:1511181118DY13328,NTRFS657DRTSF1811632//TCT023/697442
:61:1511181118DY26657466,NTRFS657DRTSF1811632//TCT023/697442
I/O CITIBANK JAPAN LTD
:62F:C151118JPY4907330,
-}{5:{CHK:347C4ABB2833}}
{1:F01FIRNZAJJACLS0991711520}{2:O9500637151118CLSBUS33DXXX10955316551511181337N}{3:{108:S201511182092379}}{4:
:20:S201511182092379
:25:100798
:28C:50/1
:60F:C151118AUD0,
:61:1511181118D2800000,NFEXFXTMAV68137396B//V20151118004496D
:61:1511181118C300000,NFEXFXTSDA68142044//V20151118002A3F7
:61:1511181118C500000,NFEXFXTSDA68131969//V2015111800616AC
:61:1511181118C1000000,NFEXFXTSDA68121455//V2015111800A79DC
:61:1511181118C1000000,NFEXFXTJGB68136823//V20151118008D7DE
:62F:C151118AUD0,
-}{5:{CHK:DFE6CC369EED}}
{1:F01FIRNZAJJACLS0991711940}{2:O9500645151118CLSBUS33AXXX12605315171511181345N}{3:{108:S201511182092422}}{4:
:20:S201511182092422
:25:100798
:28C:48/1
:60F:C151118HKD0,
:62F:C151118HKD0,
-}{5:{CHK:4E9374364F7E}}
{1:F01FIRNZAJJACLS0991712647}{2:O9500701151118CLSBUS33BXXX11318045431511181401N}{3:{108:S201511182092465}}{4:
:20:S201511182092465
:25:100798
:28C:48/1
:60F:C151118SGD0,
:61:1511181118D1300000,NFEXFXTMAV68178024A//V20151118008388F
:61:1511181118C100000,NFEXA151118000037081//V2015111800000D3
:61:1511181118C1200000,NFEXFXTMAV68138706B//V201511180074DB7
:62F:C151118SGD0,
-}{5:{CHK:34212515C8D6}}
{1:F01FIRNZAJJACLS0991712811}{2:O9500702151118CLSBUS33AXXX12605316791511181402N}{3:{108:S201511182092508}}{4:
:20:S201511182092508
:25:100798
:28C:48/1
:60F:C151118KRW0,
:62F:C151118KRW0,
-}{5:{CHK:4E90352A03A6}}
{1:F01FIRNZAJJAXXX0991713343}{2:O9502113151118BOTKJPJTAXXX19937001311511181414N}{4:
:20:216-00002
:25:653-0414247
:28C:216/00002
:60M:C151118JPY1585509238,
:61:151118D743180,NTRFS6573BCBC2471469//837-5701627
OUR CHG/COMM JPY2500,
:61:151118D843720,NTRF25-255840//837-5309398
:61:151118D1061500,NTRFSD3GR4K095LR2UQ1//837-5701839
:61:151118D1396000,NTRF25-255854//837-5309389
:61:151118D1960000,NTRF25-255842//837-5309388
:61:151118D2000000,NTRF25-255838//837-5309397
:61:151118D2577000,NTRF25-255488//837-5308764
:61:151118D26635000,NTRFS480A5502//962BTP183560
MIZUHO BANK, LTD.. HEAD OFFICE (TO
:61:151118D826936308,NTRFS6573B8BE5198313//962BTP182113
SMBC TOKYO INTER'L BUSINESS OPER. 
:62F:C151118JPY721356530,
:64:C151118JPY721356530,
-}{5:{CHK:72646A6E1228}}`

Comment: in the first and third "block", you take a string from line 5 and add it to line 2. What's with the second block? Have you tried something? We are willing to help you, but this is not a free "write my code service"

Comment: the second block was an accidental copy  sorry, I have some code where I  find everything after field :25: and save the results on a new textfile but I have no idea to only select the currency in field :62F:and place it next to the field :25: If tried getting the line numbers of all :25: and then add +2 to it to get the results of the currency but I'm not experienced enough with batch jobs.

Comment: sounds like a perfect plan (for batch at least - there may be better approaches with "real" programming languages). Show your code and we will find and show you the quirks.

Comment: Thank you here is the code so far (
echo off
SET TempFile=Temp.txt
findstr ":25:1234" test.txt >> result1.txt
findstr /n ":25:1234" test.txt >> result2.txt

findstr /i ":62M: \.:62F:" test.txt >> currency.txt


FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%G IN (result2.txt) DO 
echo %%G >>result3.txt
pause)

Comment: sorry about the way I comment stuff I'm very new at Stackoverflow.

Comment: anything ? please  @Stephan

Comment: You should edit the question (click on "edit" below the "batch-file" tag) to remove the erroneous second block and insert the code you have. You should realize that extract the code from a _comment_ is not easy...

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%c In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%c="

SET /a count=0
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q33866504.txt) DO (
 SET "$!count!=%%a"
 IF "%%a"=="-}" (
  SET "currency="
  FOR /l %%c IN (0,1,!count!) DO IF "!$%%c:~0,3!"==":62" SET "currency=!$%%c:~6!"
  FOR %%c IN (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 "," :) DO SET "currency=!currency:%%~c=!"
  FOR /l %%c IN (0,1,!count!) DO (
   IF "!$%%c:~0,3!"==":25" (ECHO !$%%c!!currency!) ELSE (ECHO !$%%c!)
  )
  FOR  /F "delims==" %%c In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%c="
  SET /a count=0
 ) ELSE (SET /a count+=1)
) >u:\newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q33866504.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces u:\newfile.txt

You don't say how to extract the currency symbol, nor do you explain the "62" business. You seem to want to select "62M" alongside "62F".

Realise that this code uses `delayedexpansion` hence `!var!` refers to the value of a variable as it changes within a loop.

First step is to clear all `$` variables in the environment. They are unlikely to exist, but this makes sure. The environment will be restored to its original state after the procedure runs, so it's of no consequence otherwise.

Set the environment variable `$!count!` for each line encountered, so the first line will go to `$0`, the next to `$1` etc.

If the line read is **not** `-}` then increment `count` (hence each new line is installed in the next `$` variable.)

If the line read **is** `-}` then set `currency` to the 6th character-on (starting at "character 0") of [the `$` variable which has `:62` as the 3 characters starting at the 0'th character].

You don't say how to extract the currency string, so I chose to remove all of the numerics, **<kbd>.</kbd>** and **<kbd>:</kbd>** from the string saved as `currency`.

Then loop through all of the `$` variables again. Reproduce each, but if the first 3 characters are `:25` then append the value of `currency` to the line.

Then clear out the `$` variables and set `count` to 0 ready for the next block.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys @Magoo the currencies ate in the fields :62F or :62M so it needs to be extracted from there and then copied next to the number of filed :25:  but only for field :25:1234 and not for any other  that can be in the same file. hope this clarifies a bit ?

Comment: To replace only `:25:1234` change `"!$%%c:~0,3!"==":25"` to `"!$%%c:~0,8!"==":25:1234"` You still don't state explicitly how to extract the currency code.

Comment: the currency gets extracted from the :62F: or :62M: field like this :62F:C15111USDS0,00 so need to take it from that field , I have tried the example that you gave me but it does not work here is the code sorry for the way I display the code:

Comment: <pre><code>IF "%%a"=="{1:" (
  SET "currency="
  FOR /l %%c IN (0,1,!count!) DO IF "!$%%c:~0,3!"==":62" SET "currency=!$%%c:~6!"
  FOR %%c IN (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 "," :) DO SET "currency=!currency:%%~c=!"
  FOR /l %%c IN (0,1,!count!) DO (
   IF "!$%%c:~0,10!"==":25:100790" (ECHO !$%%c!!currency!) ELSE (ECHO !$%%c!)
  )</code></pre>

Comment: Aacini told you how to edit your question to include more data. You've modified the code so that it will not match the sample data. I deliberately used `-}` as that appears to be end-of-block. `{1:` looks suspiciously like beginning-of-block, so the very last data block may be incomplete and deleted. You specified the format of the "25" line-start but have then changed it (correctly!) but haven't provided appropriate sample data to test against. But most important of all, you've not said in what way "it does not work" or how to extract the currency-code. We don't engage in guessing-games.

Comment: sorry about that don't want to start guessing games ... I thought the test data would be sufficient I'll give a better example

Comment: When I say it is not working is that nothing is being populated into the `newfile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get all currencies and store they in its own file
findstr "^:62F:" test.txt > currency.txt

rem Redirect input to read from currencies file
< currency.txt (
   for /F "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do (
      set "line=%%a"
      if "!line:~0,4!" equ ":25:" (
         rem Read the currency from its file and append it
         set /P "currency="
         set "line=!line!!currency:~12,3!"
      )
      echo !line!
   )
)
```

**EDIT**: *Reply to the comment*

I copied the new data into `test.txt` file. Then, I show just the lines with `:25:` or `:62F:` fields; here they are:

```
C:\> findstr ":25: :62F:" test.txt
:25:100798
:62F:C151118JPY0,
:25:0685010
:62F:C151118JPY4907330,
:25:100798
:62F:C151118AUD0,
:25:100798
:62F:C151118HKD0,
:25:100798
:62F:C151118SGD0,
:25:100798
:62F:C151118KRW0,
:25:653-0414247
:62F:C151118JPY721356530,
```

After that, I processed the `test.txt` file into `output.txt` file:

```
C:\> test.bat > output.txt
```

... and finally I show the same `:25:` or `:62F:` lines of the `output.txt` file:

```
C:\> findstr ":25: :62F:" output.txt
:25:100798JPY
:62F:C151118JPY0,
:25:0685010JPY
:62F:C151118JPY4907330,
:25:100798AUD
:62F:C151118AUD0,
:25:100798HKD
:62F:C151118HKD0,
:25:100798SGD
:62F:C151118SGD0,
:25:100798KRW
:62F:C151118KRW0,
:25:653-0414247JPY
:62F:C151118JPY721356530,
```

As you can see, each `:25:` field have the currency of its corresponding `:62F:` one as requested, so I don't understand what is the problem...

**IMPORTANT**: Before you post any further reply or comment you should repeat the test above so you can confirm by yourself that previous results are the ones obtained by my code, indeed. Any further discussion about my code will take as base the previous result!

Comment: if I run it with more data it only copies one currency for everything  see this :`:25:100798ZAR
:25:100798ZAR
:25:100798ZAR
:25:100798ZAR
:25:100798ZAR
:25:100798ZAR
:25:100798ZAR
:25:100798ZAR
:25:100798ZAR
:25:100798ZAR
:25:100798ZAR
:25:100798ZAR
:25:100798ZAR
:25:100798ZAR` and it must be this `:25:100798JYP
:25:100798ZAR
:25:100798ZAR
:25:100798SGD
:25:100798ZAR
:25:100798ZAR
:25:100798ZAR
:25:100798ZAR
:25:100798ZARZAR
:25:100798ZAR
:25:100798ZAR
:25:100798NOK
:25:100798CHF
:25:100798SEK`  what can it be ?

Comment: @Christiaan: How can I know that if I have not the input data that produce such output? **`:(`** I don't like to guess things! Do you want that I guess any data and show you the results that I obtained with data that you don't know? **`:/`** Just post a more complete example data _in the question_! Note that _for the purposes of a solution for this problem_ you may post just the `:25:` and `:62F:` lines, because all other lines are not modified _accordingly to your specifications_.

Comment: please check the question I posted more relative data I thought by only giving a piece would be sufficient

Comment: It works but for every field `:25:` but say you only want the to get the currency next to the field: `25:100198` and not for the other field `:25:` ?

Comment: Excuse me, I don't understand what "the _other_ field `:25:`" means. You must be much clearer. Post something like "in line `XXXXX` the result was `YYYYY`, but it should be `ZZZZZ` because xxx yyy zzz..."

Comment: you must only let the field `:25:100798` be changed to `:25:100798(corresponding Currency)` if the field `:62F:` or :62M:` is part of the corresponded group each group starts with `{1:` and ends with `{5:` so if you have a field `:25:1230` it should NOT change only the field `:25:100798` should be changed hope this helps in making it clear ??

Comment: @Christiaan: Yes it is clear _now_, but all these _new_ points does **not** appear in the question and I am not a mind-reader! Anyway, the field `:25:1230` you refer in your comment does **not** appear in your example data, so you are talking about input data that I can not test, **again**! It seems you didn't read the **IMPORTANT** note in my answer. If you assert that my code fails with certain data, why you didn't posted such data? Sorry, but I am tired of this guessing-game...

Comment: Good day I'm using the `:25:1230` as a pure example not as a given. lets use `:25:0685010` then it should only change the `:25:100798` to `:25:100798USD` or what ever currency is in the corresponding `:62:F` or `:62:M` field